# DownloadDataAsync and DownloadFile Async not working

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadfileasync

When I use DownloadDataAsync with DownloadDataCompleted, the progress bar works, it says "SUCCESS" but I couldn't find any file! Why?

When I use DownloadFileAsync with DownloadFileCompleted, it fails to download from the start. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = @"C:\\sample.flv";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://root.alpha.lh:88/4ever.flv");

    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);

}
```

Functions like `wc_*` do exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the application has the permissions to write directly to `c:\`?  By default most applications won't.

In the case that you don't the code will fire the `DownloadFileCompleted` event but it will have an exception value in the `Error` property of `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`